# Create text mask using ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick, mask, node-imagemagick

I need to create an image from some background and text, like:

[image: example]

I try

```
convert -size 320x100 xc:transparent \
        -font Arial -pointsize 72 -tile "bg.jpg" \
        -annotate +28+68 'Some text' clear.png
```

but this does not work.

Comment: What's not working about the command you've tried?

Comment: yes, according to the documentation should work

Comment: It works for me on ImageMagick 6.8.5. Are you getting an error message, or exit code?

Comment: Thank you, I understand. The problem was that the background in jpg. If background in png its work

Comment: @ИванДрондов: If you solved your problem by using a PNG background instead of JPEG, you should write an answer (even to your own question) outlining exactly that. (This way the answer may even be upvoted, and you can gain reputation points too...)

Answer (score 0):

*Use the following command:*

```
magick -gravity center input.jpg ( +clone -threshold 101% -fill white -font berlin-sans-fb-bold -pointsize 124 -draw "text 0,0 Hello" ) -alpha off -compose copyopacity -composite -trim output.png
```

[image]